# How to create parameters for HMM model of online handwriting recognition?

Tags: hidden-markov-models

I'm a little inexperienced about Hidden Markov Model. If I want to make a model of HMM for online handwriting recognition (which means handwriting recognition of letter that user draw live on device instead of recognizing image of letter), how is the parameter model? Like what are the:

- hidden states,
- observations,
- initial state probabilities,
- state transition probabilities,
- emission probabilities?

What I have right now maybe the observations, which is the array of { x, y, timestamp } that is each dot that I record from the user's finger movement on the tablet.

The system will only record/train/recognize one number at a time. Which means I have 10 (0 to 9) states???? Or 10 classification results?? From various website like [this](https://www.math.unl.edu/%7Esdunbar1/ProbabilityTheory/Lessons/HiddenMarkovModels/Examples/examples.html), I found that hidden states usually in form of "sequences", instead of one single state like that. What is the states then in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HMMs work well with temporal data, but it may be a suboptimal fit for this problem.

As you've identified, the *observations* {x, y, timestamp} are temporal in nature. As a result, it is best cast as the *emissions* of the HMM, while reserving the digits as *states* of the HMM.

- Explicitly, if numbers (0 to 9) are encoded as hidden states, then for a 100 x 100 "image", the emission can be one of 10000 possible pixels coordinates.
- The model predicts a digit state at every timestamp (on-line). The output is a non-unique pixel location. This is cumbersome but not impossible to encode (you'd just have a huge emission matrix).
- The initial state probabilities of which digit to start can be a uniform distribution (1/10). More cleverly, you can invoke *Benford's law* to approximate the frequency of digits appearing in text and distribute your starting probability accordingly.
- State transition and emission probabilities are tricky. One strategy is to train your HMM using the **Baum-Welch** (a variation of Expectation-Maximization) algorithm to iteratively and agnostically estimate parameters for your transition and emission matrices. The training data would be known digits with pixel locations registered across time.

Casting the problem the other way is less natural because of this lack of temporal fit, but not impossible.

- You can also make 10000 possible states aligning to the pixels, while having 10 emissions (0-9).
- However, most commonly used algorithms for HMMs have run times quadratically related to number of states ( ie. Viterbi algorithm for the most likely valid hidden states runs **O(n_emissions * n_states^2))**. You are incentivized to keep the number of hidden states low.

---

**Unsolicited suggestions**

Maybe what you might be looking for are Kalman filters, which may be a more elegant way to develop this on-line digit recognition (outside of CNNs which appear to the most effective) using this time-series format.

You may also want to look at structured perceptrons, if your emissions are multivariate (ie. x, y) and independent. Here, I believe x, y coordinates should be correlated and should be respected as such.

Comment: Hi. Sorry it took long to get back to you. Since then, I have gained some more understanding about the nature of my problem. But I still have related problem. So if on your answer you suggest for me to divide the pixel into 100 x 100, that is if the features inside the observation is actually { x, y, timestamp }. The problem is, according to common online handwriting recognition using HMM, those points should be preprocessed and then get their features extracted, which I ends up with each point now have 6 feature elements.

Comment: Those six features are { NDTSE, normalized y, vicinity slope alpha sin, vicinity slope alpha cos, curvature beta sin, curvature beta cos }. Here's the paper that explain this: https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.226.3759&rep=rep1&type=pdf I'm not sure how to model the observation *symbols* out of vector with 6 elements like this.

Comment: Unfortunately, due to the nature of the project situation, I can't switch to other methods like Karman filters. But maybe I'll take a look to see if there's something in the Karman filter method that can aid me in this HMM observation symbolism matter.

Comment: It is clear from the paper that the hidden **states** are cast as the 6 element feature space. "In this paper, we set the initial **state** distribution to be π = 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 and keep it fixed during the training process". Your observations should be the 10 digits {0, 1, ... 9}. You'll output a "sequence" of these observations (ie. 1, 1, 1, 1, 7, 7, 1, 1, 1). As a start, you can take the consensus of the observation sequence. The example I provided is pertinent: 1 looks like the character 7. Your model may at certain points think the written digit is 7 instead of 1.

Comment: batlike isn't it supposed to be: 10 HMM for 10 digits (classification result), each HMM can evaluate given observations to produce how much probability each HMM model can produce the said stroke, and then I select the highest probability? For example, HMM model that was trained using multiple samples similar to number 8, will given higher probability in subsequent evaluation of stroke observation similar to number 8, than HMM that's trained with multiple samples similar to number 7, for example? My main problem is to determine the observation "symbols", rather than the states themselves.

Comment: The examples I get from the internet, usually have the observation "symbols" of a concrete, discrete type, like an enumeration. We can make enumeration symbol for, say, "Red", "Green", "Blue". So the observation can be { Red, Red, Blue, Green, Red }. But how if the observation result is RGB values? How if the observations { (210, 30, 52), (95, 170, 24), (103, 89, 230), ... } ? Does that mean we have to make observation symbols enlisting all possible 255x255x255 combination? And in my case, the whole 6 elements of features are all floating points instead of known 0..255 integer value.

Comment: "10 HMM for 10 digits (classification result)". I don't have the bandwidth to explain in detail how HMMs work, but I think you're missing the point here. The observations should be the 10 digits, and can be encoded into what you call "one" HMM. The HMM will help you "predict" based on your 6 features what it believes the digit is being written, temporally.

Comment: "The examples I get from the internet, usually have the observation "symbols" of a concrete, discrete type". Please read my answer again carefully, I think you are confusing observations with hidden states. The 6 features that describe your digit should be your hidden state, NOT your observation. You observe the digit; the hidden states are the 6 features that describe the digit being written. You made it clear you want to predict the digit (observation) given a 6-feature-long vector (states).

Comment: As for your question about encoding a continuous space for your states, this is an entirely separate question - I encourage you to look at *state space models*. HMMs will not satisfy your project here, if this is the case. One place to start is to discretize your observations into "bins".

Comment: Of course, you *can* choose to invert the analogy, by using the digits as hidden states and the 6 features as continuous observations. Many HMM libraries will support a distribution that describes the observation space (ie. multinomial, Gaussian, uniform, etc.). This will allow you to model your continuous 6-feature space. However, here, because you have 6 features as opposed to 1 emission, you would need to employ a **structured perceptron**. Again, HMMs will not be sufficient for your project. If you are still interested, ***please*** ask a separate question.

Comment: batlike okay, I will need to explore around first with some options you mentioned, but thank you with your suggestion, it gave me some ideas to try. Thank you for the help.